# figure out $f(n)$ under given conditions

Tags: elementary-number-theory, functions

Suppose I need a function $f(n)$ such that $f(n)$ is odd when $n=4,12,20,28...$ and even when $n=8,16,24,32...$. Then the answer would be $f(n)=\frac{n}{4}$.

Similarly, now suppose I need $f(n)$ such that $f(n)$ is even when $n=1,3;9,11;17,19;25,27...$ and odd when $n=5,7;13,15;21,23...$. What could $f(n)$ in this case be?

I have tried to generate a function $f(n)$ which gives $2$ when $n=1,3$; $10$ when $n=9,11$ and so on. But I can't seem to figure out a way. How should I proceed?

One of the answers below mentions the floor function. Could a continuous function be possible or is this a unique answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f(n)=\dfrac{\sin(\pi(n-1)/4)+\cos(\pi(n-1)/4)-1}{2}$ also works.

There are infinitely many solutions.  [Here is a related thread on oeis for the sequence $(1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,\ldots)$](http://oeis.org/A133872).

Answer (score 0):

Use the floor function:
$$f(n)=\lfloor n/4 \rfloor$$

Comment: Is it possible to get a continuous function?